# Processing: Error for code that's not used

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to measure the time it takes to run some of my functions, but I get an error in Processing: playInvadersMoveSoundStart cannot be resolved to a variable.

In the top of my document:

```
boolean debug;
```

And in setup:

```
debug = false;
```

Main Draw:

```java
case 2:
    background(0);
    if (debug){
        double gameLoopStart = millis();
        println("fps " +frameRate);
        int playInvadersMoveSoundStart = millis();
    }
    playInvadersMoveSound();
    if (debug){
        int playInvadersMoveSoundEnd = millis();
        int playInvadersMoveSoundTime = (playInvadersMoveSoundEnd - playInvadersMoveSoundStart);
        println("playInvadersMoveSound " +playInvadersMoveSoundTime);
        int displayBunkersStart = millis();
    }
```

I'm very new a Processing and programming in general so it's probably something I don't understand, but I think that the code would run fine if processing would stop doing error checking. I mean - Debug is set to false so the code Processing is complaining about doesn't run. right?

Comment: You can comment those lines if they're unused and you want to keep them around. Select the lines and hit ` Ctrl ` + ` / `

Comment: @laancelot I know but I was trying to make a boolean I can set to false in order to avoid commenting out all of my "debug".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `playInvadersMoveSoundStart` is declared in the block scope of the `if` statement:

```java
if (debug){
    // [...]
    int playInvadersMoveSoundStart = millis();
}
```

So the variable is not accessible outside the block scope of the `if` statement. 
Move the variable declaration before the `if`:

```java
case 2:
{
    background(0);

    int playInvadersMoveSoundStart = 0;
    if (debug){
        double gameLoopStart = millis();
        println("fps " +frameRate);
        playInvadersMoveSoundStart = millis();
    }
    playInvadersMoveSound(); 
    if (debug){
        int playInvadersMoveSoundEnd = millis();
        int playInvadersMoveSoundTime = playInvadersMoveSoundEnd - playInvadersMoveSoundStart;
        println("playInvadersMoveSound " +playInvadersMoveSoundTime);
    }
}
```